# Image showing in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.android

I am new to xamarin and android.I am trying to create  a sample application .I want to show a bitmap in the application.I have written code and compiled successfully.When I run using emulator it is crashing and I am not able to understand why.Even I put break point in the method it is not hitting.

How to debug and understand the problem

Image getting method:

```
 public static Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
    {
        Bitmap imageBitmap = null;
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
            if(imageBytes!=null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
            {
                imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes,0,imageBytes.Length);
            }
        }
        return imageBitmap;
    }
```

Code where I am using this method

```
var imageBitmap = ImageHelper.GetImageBitmapFromUrl("http://theopentutorials.com/totwp331/wp-content/uploads/totlogo.png");
hotDogImageView.SetImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
```

I am trying to debug by keeping breakpoint at imageBitmap to see may be it is coming null but break point not hitting.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: I will let u know once I try.Now I switched to another task so paused that work.thank u

Answer (score 0):

> Image showing in Xamarin.Android

There are some third-party library which implements this feature quite well like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Glide.Xamarin/).

For example, you could try using [Glide](https://github.com/beraybentesen/glide-xamarin-android) to implement this feature easily:

1. Download the `Glide` nuget package:

[image]

2. Display an internet image on an `ImageView` control:

   ```
   Glide
       .With(this)
       .Load("http://theopentutorials.com/totwp331/wp-content/uploads/totlogo.png")
       .Apply(RequestOptions.CircleCropTransform())
       .Into(imageView);
   ```

## Update:

You could change the target version in your `Xamarin.Android` `Properties`:

[image]
[image]

If your Android emulator OS version is lower than your project minimum android version, then you can't deploy the project to your emulator.

Comment: Error  Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations 25.4.0.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.   0

Comment: What is your project target version? Android 6.0? You need change your target version to Android 7.0 or higher.

Comment: how to change it?? I tired changing minimum android version to Android 7.0 but then I am not able to get Emulator option to run the project

Comment: @NAGASREE, I have updated my answer, you may check it.

Comment: I have tried that also,still getting same error.In visual studio it is having emulator till Android 6 Marshallow

Comment: @NAGASREE, please post your complete error stack trace.